# Angularjs custom filter that exactly work like normal in build filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a code in jsfiddle. Where I use normal in build filter service in angularjs. But I need a custom filter service which exactly behave same like normal filter. I have to use custom filter because after filtering I have to do some custom operation. My jsfiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/subhajitmaity/jzpmg1um/3/

Please go through the link.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='AppCtrl'>
<input type="text" ng-model="search">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="categoryTree">
        {{ category.title }}
        <ul ng-if="category.categories">
            <li ng-repeat="category in category.categories | filter:search" ng-include="'categoryTree'">           
            </li>
        </ul>
    </script>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="category in categories | filter:search" ng-include="'categoryTree'"></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't want to use in build filter. Rather than want to use a custom filter that behave like same as in build filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from this custom filter:

```
app.filter('myfilter', function() {
   return function( items, search) {
    var filtered = [];

    if(!search){
      return items;
    }

      angular.forEach(items, function(item){     
          if(item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
             filtered.push(item);
          }
      })      

    return filtered;
  };
});
```

*Usage:*

```
| myfilter:search
```

---

The problem stays: parent filter should return `true` if one of the children contains one of `search`

Comment: Its only filter the first level.Not working properly. How to solve the problem?

Comment: @Rahul `How to solve the problem? ` there is no problem but pure code writing. Post your code what you did so far. You have enough code snippet examples  how to filter nested arrays.

Comment: I put my code in plunker.Just see the above link. Unable to solve the situation that's why seeking for help

Comment: @Rahul well, in your demo you use default filter and you ask that someone will write for you custom filter and fitter nested array of objects. I think its out of StackOveflow goal. Here we help to fix exist code but not write code from scratch. I posted you example of custom filter. Use it, its a good start. Write your own logic inside custom filter , show where you stuck. No one want to spend his time to write code for you.